# Drop-down Menu of Checkboxes in An HTML form

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

In HTML, what is the easiest way to create a drop-down list of checkboxes?

By this, I mean a user is able to select one Or many checkbox items from the drop-down.

Comment: you can try with jquery

Comment: the easiest way is **place a drop-down menu of checkboxes in a form**

Comment: Use a select-field with multi-select for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select multiple="true" size="5">
    <option>Option</option>
    <option>Option</option>
    <option>Option</option>
    <option>Option</option>
    <option>Option</option>
</select>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hsL4z/

Select multiple while holding CTRL, otherwise make a scrollable div with regular checkboxes.

Comment: It's a good recommendation, but requires instructions as most people wouldn't think to hold CTRL.

Comment: That's true, but could very much be useful for backends that is in own control without requiring any fancy stuff.

Answer (score 0):

you can use https://github.com/scottwb/jquery.ui.dropdownchecklist.
Visit, https://code.google.com/p/dropdown-check-list, if you want to see how it looks like.